# Is it possible to serialize some object using pickle and use it in other independent module in Python3?

Tags: python, sockets, serialization, pickle

I have 2 independent files:
The first one is **client.py** and in it i should create some object using **Record** and then to serialize it using pickle class and then to send it with socket to the second file which is **server.py** and the server should de-serialize this bytes object to the original object

client.py:

```
from pyrecord import Record
import pickle

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSock.connect(("localhost",48621))
Message1Obj=Record.create_type('Message1Obj','name','address')
message1Data = Message1Obj("KB","aa")
message1Serlization = pickle.dumps(message1Data)
clientSock.send(message1Serlization)
```

server.py

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("localhost",48621))
sock.listen(5)
con,adr = sock.accept()

message1 = con.recv(8192)
Message1Obj = pickle.loads(message1)
```

but i get this error on the servers.py:

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Message1Obj' on module '**main**' from 'server.py'

I understood from previous answers that pickle.dump saves also the module that the object is in, Is it possible to load the serialized object in other module?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pickle to serialize the I have used dill to serialize 
my python object and send over server in binary string format.

```
message1Data = {'A message or function/class object'}
 import dill
 s_data = dill.dumps(message1Data)
```

send to server through some socket and De-serialize it there

```
org_data = dill.loads(s_data)
```